# How do i build a query that averages scores in a db based on another column

Tags: javascript, mysql

Right now I have a table "uniqueids" that looks like:

```js
+----+-----------------+------+-------+------------+
| id | uniqueid        | name | score | date       |
+----+-----------------+------+-------+------------+
|  1 | bob1            | bob  |     4 | 02-10 |
|  2 | bob2            | bob  |    49 | 02-15 |
|  3 | bob3            | bob  |    48 | 03-01 |
|  4 | cari1           | cari |    76 | 02-15 |
|  5 | cari2           | cari |    60 | 02-16 |
|  6 | cari3           | cari |    71 | 03-05 |
|  7 | john1           | john |    54 | 01-05 |
|  8 | john2           | john |    56 | 02-13 |
|  9 | john3           | john |    53 | 03-13 |
+----+-----------------+------+-------+------------+
```

What i want is to take the average score for each name. So in the end I'd get something along the lines of:

```js
+----+---------
|name  | score |
+----+---------
|bob   |  33.6 |
|cari  |  69   |
|john  |  54.3 |
---------------
```

There could be more names added to the database later, but for now I've been focusing on just doing this for one name. My progress on one name is this:

'SELECT * from uniqueids where name='bob' and SELECT AVG(score)' but this doesn't work for me, it just mentions I have an error in my syntax. Even if it did, it would only do it for bob, whereas I'd need it done for each name.

Any ideas on what I can do to get this query to where I need it to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty standard SQL query. You just need to combine the `avg` function with a suitable `group by` clause (and with the `where` clause if you want to limit the result to a specific name).

```
select name, avg(score) as "average score"
from uniqueids 
where name = 'bob' -- remove this line if you want averages for all names
group by name
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b62ef9/4)

Answer (score 0):

**select name, avg(score) Score
from uniqueids
group by name;**
this would help you get the desired answer.